# How to call javascript function in item template when using gridview

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, gridview

I am trying to call a javascript function which will set forecolor and backcolor of a control when the control is loaded

But this function is not raising.

```
<ItemTemplate>
      <div onload= "invertColor(this,'<%# Eval("ColorCode") %>')">
           <%# Eval("ColorCode") %>
      </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Here is my javascript

```
    function invertColor(sender, backColor) {
        alert('hi');
//        alert(backColor.toString());
//        if (backColor != '') {
//        
//            sender.css('background-color', backColor);
//            backColor= backColor.substr(1, 6);
//            foreColor = numberToHex(255 - parseInt(backColor.substr(0, 2), 16))
//            + numberToHex(255 - parseInt(backColor.substr(2, 2), 16))
//            + numberToHex(255 - parseInt(backColor.substr(4, 2), 16));
//            sender.css('color', "#"+foreColor)
//        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it immediately after the div if the element has some way to address it, like and id or css class. making the div a server control will produce a unique id for each item in the collection.

```
<ItemTemplate> 
      <div runat="server" id="dummy"> 
           <%# Eval("ColorCode") %> 
      </div> 
    <script> invertColor('<% =dummy.ClientID %>', '<%# Eval("ColorCode") %>'); </script>
</ItemTemplate>
```

here i've changed the first parameter to a string instead of an object. inside `invertColor` you can use the id string to get a reference to the element however you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's not going to work because there's no onload event on a div. Why not just set an appropriate CSS class?

Comment: I have to call a javascript function that will be inverting my backcolor and displaying it as a forecolor. So using css i cant call javascript

Comment: you can use inline-style for the div.

Comment: As Hoque says, you can use an inline-style. Or, if you're using the same colours in multiple places you can use a css class and push the appropriate <style> block out from the server. I can see no point in doing this from the client, unless there's stuff you haven't gone into yet.

Answer (score 0):

Using in-line style

```
<ItemTemplate> 
  <div style= "color:<%# Eval("ColorCode") %>"> 
       <%# Eval("ColorCode") %> 
  </div> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

might be an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Link"> 
 <ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HLink" 
        Text='<%# Eval("FirstName").ToString() + " " + Eval("LastName").ToString()%>' 
        NavigateUrl='<%# "javascript:OpenPopup(" + "&#39;" + Eval("EmpId") + "&#39;);" %> ' />
 </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```